# How to set adf_path and build a project for LYRA-T board?

Tags: esp-idf

"Warn about uninitialized values.
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:5 (include):
uninitialized variable 'ADF_PATH'
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (include):
include could not find load file:
/CMakeLists.txt

-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe (found version "2.25.1.windows.1")
-- Unexpected file in components directory: C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/.gitkeep
-- ccache will be used for faster recompilation
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2019r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
warning: the default selection SR_RUN_WM6_CORE1 (undefined) of (defined at C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-sr/Kconfig.projbuild:83) is not contained in the choice
warning: the default selection CONFIG_SR_MN1_MODEL_QUANT (undefined) of (defined at C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-sr/Kconfig.projbuild:100) is not contained in the choice
-- App "play_mp3" version: v2.0-beta2-21-g30403e2-dirty
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/Embedded/.espressif/python_env/idf4.2_py2.7_env/Scripts/python.exe (found version "2.7.12")
-- Could NOT find Perl (missing: PERL_EXECUTABLE)
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-adf/examples/get-started/play_mp3/build/esp-idf/esp32/esp32_out.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/ld/esp32.project.ld.in
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs-time.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-data.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.syscalls.ld
-- Adding linker script C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs.ld
-- Current board name is CONFIG_ESP_LYRAT_V4_3_BOARD
-- Components: adf_utils app_trace app_update asio audio_board audio_hal audio_pipeline audio_sal audio_stream bluetooth_service bootloader bootloader_support bt cbor clouds coap console cxx display_service driver dueros_service efuse esp-adf-libs esp-sr esp-tls esp32 esp_actions esp_adc_cal esp_common esp_dispatcher esp_eth esp_event esp_gdbstub esp_http_client esp_http_server esp_https_ota esp_https_server esp_local_ctrl esp_netif esp_peripherals esp_ringbuf esp_rom esp_serial_slave_link esp_timer esp_websocket_client esp_wifi espcoredump esptool_py expat fatfs freemodbus freertos heap idf_test input_key_service jsmn json libsodium log lwip main mbedtls mdns mqtt newlib nghttp nvs_flash openssl partition_table perfmon playlist protobuf-c protocomm pthread sdmmc soc spi_flash spiffs tcp_transport tcpip_adapter ulp unity vfs wear_levelling wifi_provisioning wifi_service wpa_supplicant xtensa
-- Component paths: C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/adf_utils C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/app_trace C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/app_update C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/asio C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/audio_board C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/audio_hal C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/audio_pipeline C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/audio_sal C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/audio_stream C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/bluetooth_service C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/bt C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/cbor C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/clouds C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/coap C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/console C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/cxx C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/display_service C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/driver C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/dueros_service C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-adf-libs C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-sr C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32 C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_actions C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_adc_cal C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_dispatcher C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_eth C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_event C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_gdbstub C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_http_client C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_https_ota C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_https_server C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_local_ctrl C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_netif C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_peripherals C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_serial_slave_link C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_timer C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_websocket_client C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/espcoredump C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/expat C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/freemodbus C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/heap C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/idf_test C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/input_key_service C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/jsmn C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/json C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/libsodium C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/log C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-adf/examples/get-started/play_mp3/main C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/mdns C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/nghttp C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/openssl C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/perfmon C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/playlist C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/protobuf-c C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/protocomm C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/pthread C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/sdmmc C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/soc C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/spiffs C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/ulp C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/unity C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/vfs C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/wifi_provisioning C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/wifi_service C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Embedded/Desktop/esp/esp-adf/examples/get-started/play_mp3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
cmake failed with exit code 1
"

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! This question would need some additional information to help you get an answer. Add some details about how you encountered this error, what you expected to happen and what you already tried to get past it. Good luck finding your solution :)

Comment: Thank you for replying  William Patton.
From this link "https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-adf/en/latest/get-started/ " 
i have started to build accordingly.
First i have set up environment for ESP-IDF and then for ESP-ADF.
for ESP-IDF "https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/get-started/index.html" i follow these setup

Comment: @EmbelTechnologies did you find any solutions? I'm still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

if using Windows : 
in IDF command prompt

`set ADF_PATH = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\esp-adf"`

to ensure your path

`echo %ADF_PATH%`

Permanent solution  :add the following at the end of export.bat (found in IDF folder)

`set ADF_PATH = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\esp-adf"`